# How do you declare an optional condition for an ActiveRecord belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Rails ActiveRecord provides an `optional` option for `belongs_to`. Consider the use case of allowing null for the foreign key and allowing the association to be null during object creation but requiring its presence during subsequent saves. For example, a new Member may have no initial Group, but any further updates of Member require a Group association.

Can the `optional` option value itself be conditional? For example,

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group, optional: -> { new_record? }
end
```

behaves the same as `optional: true`, and we can infer that the `optional` option parsing only checks for a truthy value.

Is a custom validator the pragmatic way to meet this use case?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like providing a lambda to the `optional` option won't work (although I haven't tried it). I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/belongs_to.rb#L144) and this is how `optional` is used.

```
required = !reflection.options[:optional]
```

If required, Rails just adds a presence validation like this:

```
model.validates_presence_of reflection.name, message: :required
```

I believe you could go the custom route with something like this:

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group, optional: true
  validates :group, presence: true, on: :update
end
```

Comment: Indeed. Thank you for citing the source.

Comment: For what it's worth, Rails 7 / Ruby 3 allow lambdas in `optional` now.

`belongs_to :group, optional: Proc.new { |a| a.new_record? }`

Comment: @BeerMe where did you read about it?

Comment: @Stiig Of course, I can't find it now. But the Active Record Associations guide says:

> 4.1.2.11 :optional
> If you set the :optional option to true, then the presence of the associated object won't be validated. By default, this option is set to false.

So if your Proc returns `true` or `false`, it will work.

(Sorry...blockquote formatting isn't working for me.)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't describing a database constraint, you're describing business logic. Add a validator to enforce the condition:

```
validates :group, presence: true, on: :update
```

This only enforces the condition on update, not create.

Answer (score 0):

I came into the same problem. My solution is to override `belongs_to` and add an `unless` option which takes a symbol for a predicate function. It seems like a good idea...

That way you can write `belongs_to :group, unless: :new_record?`

Here is my code

```
  def self.belongs_to(name, scope = nil, options = {})
    if scope.is_a?(Hash)
      options = scope
      scope   = nil
    end

    if options.has_key? :unless
      super name, scope, options.merge(optional: true).except(:unless)
      validates name, presence: true, if: ->{ !self.send(options[:unless]) }
    else
      super
    end
  end
```